# full width on the row class in twitter bootstrap 3.0 in mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am building a website and when the website responds to mobile, the dark bar holding the navbar is a few pixels shy of full width.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper hidden-xs">
<!--Header Section-->
<div class="row backgroundColor"> 
  <!--Navigation-->
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation"> 
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://ljferris.com"><img src="images/featherLogo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Imagine Logo" /></a> </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="portfolio" data-toggle="dropdown">Portfolio <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Web Development</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Academia</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Connect</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /.navbar-collapse --> 
</nav>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#wrapper{
    max-width: 1400px;
}

.row{
    margin: 0 !important;
}

/** Navigation **/
.backgroundColor{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #313131;
}

.navbar{
    height: 80px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0;
    -0-border-radius: 0 0;
     border-radius: 0 0;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #061b33;
     border-right: none;
     border-left: none;
     border-top: none;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     background-color: #313131;
     font-size: 16px;
}
.navbar-brand{
    padding: 15px 122px 0 122px;
}

.navbar-nav{
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-right: 80px;
    float: right;
    text-transform: none;
    font-weight: 100;
}

.navbar-nav li{
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.navbar-nav>li>a{
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #EC5657 !important;
}


.navbar-nav>li>a:hover{
    color: #d7d7d7 !important;
    background-color:  #EC5657;

    -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -0-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
     transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-nav>.open>a:focus{
    background-color: transparent !important;
}

.dropdown-menu{
    background-color: #313131;
    border-top: 3px solid #fff;
    margin-top: -10px !important;
    z-index: 999999;

}

.dropdown-menu>li>a{
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #EC5657 !important;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover{
    color: #d7d7d7 !important;
    background-color: transparent;

    -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -0-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
     transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

@media (max-width: 768px){
    .navbar{
        border: none;
    }

    .navbar-brand{
        padding: 10px 0 0 20px;
    }

    ul.navbar-nav{
        background-color: #131313;
    }

    .navbar-collapse.in{
        margin-top: 13px;
    }

    ul.nav.navbar-nav{
        background-color: transparent;
        border-top: none;

    }

    #bs-example-navbar-collapse-1{
        z-index: 999999;
        float: right;
        border-top: none;
    }
```

The website is http://ljferris.com - is there anyone out there that could help me with my problem?

Comment: when I look at it the nav bar is more like 50% width. Is 'a few pixels shy of full width' irony or am I missing something?

Comment: edited the question to reflect the the problem is with the dark bar holding the navbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the side margins on `#information`. You have to remove it at smaller sizes. Actually, that's just the thinking that likely caused problem - BS3 is built the other way around. It's bitten me a few times. Mobile first = no margin by default and then you *add* it at larger sizes.

```
#information { 
    margin: 20px 0; 
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    #information { 
        margin: 20px; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You problem is not the menu. It's the footer causing trouble. You need to properly format your rows and column classes.

I suggest you not to use bootstrap classes and your classes on same element and set margin / padding.

@will already pointed the problem out. Beaten by 43 seconds ;)